# Are there gamepad compatible drones which are able to record high-quality video or carry weight of camera?

Tags: drone

There is Ryzen Tello, which can be controlled by **gamepad + smartphone**, but on their FAQ page they said that they support only Gamestir controllers and video quality is not very good (though I've seen videos where people was able to control it with some latency using other controllers).
Can't say about preferable price range, but **affordability is appreciated.**
And quality of video: my smartphone has more pixels than one good model of photocamera, though camera of course has better quality of images.
But I would say starting from **720p** would be ok, if video-quality is not smartphone-like.
Or may be I could **attach lighweight camera** to the cameraless drone.

For people who already have a gamepad compatable with Android (MADCATZ CTRL Z for instance)?

Comment: I would recommend posting a target price to receive more relevant recommendations.

Comment: @Bennett Yeo I kind of did, now.